# how does GDM set ulimits (Fedora)?

Tags: linux, fedora, ulimit

On Fedora FC20. /etc/security/limits.conf has:

```
* soft nofile 60000
* hard nofile 60000
* soft nproc 30000
* hard nproc 30000
```

After logging in through GDM, and opening a shell, the limits are `60000` for files (right), and `1024` for number of processes.

I'm trying to understand how does GDM (or what else in the process of starting up X session) set the ulimits, specifically restricting the `nproc`. I tried inserting `ulimit -u 30000` into `/etc/X11/xinit/Xsession`, and that didn't help either.

There are no ulimit statements anywhere in profile files, neither in `/etc/` nor in `~/`

(the reason I care is because I have X apps that start running out of fork due to this ulimit, and I don't feel like running them from a terminal).

Answer (score 0):

On newer Linux'es, when you set the limits in `/etc/security/limits.conf` look (especially if changes don't seem to work) into `/etc/security/limits.d/`. Files in this directory are processed after `limits.conf`, and override any changes in order.

Specifically to address https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=432903, there was a soft cap put on `nproc` for all the users besides root, to

> prevent accidental fork bombs.

In other words, always check `/etc/security/limits.conf` and `/etc/security/limits.d/` for your ulimits (and thoroughly read limits.conf(5) which I should have done in the beginning).